# Regex to remove known number of bytes from scalar variable

Tags: regex, perl

I have a scalar variable `$var` with 10 bytes in it. To remove those 10 bytes I used

```
$var =~ s/^(.{$numberOfbytes})//;
```

This works fine if there are less than 10 bytes. But I want to remove more than 4500 bytes at a time. How can I do this?

Comment: Yeah, why not substr() ?

Comment: You're missing the `s` of `s///s` to make that work for arbitrary bytes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don't use a regular expression; instead, use `substr`:

```
my $manyBytes = substr($var, 0, 4500, '');
```

That last argument makes it so that the 4500 bytes are removed from `$var`. The 4500 bytes, instead of being in `$1`, are now in `$manyBytes`.

Comment: It works fine but those 4500 bytes still present in '$var'. I want to pullout bytes from that variable, means $var should be free from those 4500 bytes.

Comment: No, they aren't.  The fourth parameter to `substr` is used to replace the value in the original string.

Answer (score 1):

```
$var = substr($var, 4500);
```

or

```
substr($var, 0, 4500, '');
```

The latter returns the removed characters.

Answer (score 1):

To remove a specified number of characters at the beginning of a string, use [substr](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/substr.html):

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $var = "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.";
my $numberOfbytes = 32;
$var = substr($var, $numberOfbytes);
print "Result: [$var]\n";
```

**Expected result:**

```
Result: [the lazy dog.]
```

Comment: After going through all answers i used '$x = substr($var,0,4500)' to copy the bytes into a variable '$x' because i needed for further analysis. And to remove those bytes i used '$var=substr($var,4500)'. So instead of writing two statements how can i achieve it in single statement?

Comment: with `$removedBytes = substr($var,0,$numberOfbytes,'');`

Answer (score 0):

I was missing the s of s///s to make that work for arbitrary bytes.
The below code works fine.

```
$numberOfbytes = 4500;
$var=~ s/^(.{$numberOfbytes})//s;
$removedBytes = $1;
```

Comment: maximum number usable that way is 32766.

Comment: @ysth is there any alternative to overcome this limitation?

Comment: no.  use `$rermovedBytes = substr($var, 0, $numberOfbytes, '');`; it ends up calling the same code internally in perl anyway.